# Failure recovery problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a problem like this:

> I have a computer that fails with chance p. I split a job into
>   sequential parts each 1 step. I run them 1 by 1 on computer and each one takes time T. To be able to recover from fails, I make
>   checkpoints every x step with time C*T, so when fail, I recover from last
>   checkpoint. how I need to select x, to have best time for system
>   overall? if I make backup every turn, overall time will so very
>   big,because making checkpoint takes a lot time if I make backup very
>   rarely, I need to fall back too many steps when a failure happens. so
>   x must be a good number.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Update:
I have tried to calculate expected time between 2 checkpoints in this way:
O-----f--O O=checkpoint -=step f=failure x=number of steps
$$
E(t) = x*T*(1-p)^x + \sum_{f=1}^\infty (x*T*(f+1)*x^f*p^f*(1-p)^{f*(x-1)})
$$
which can be completely wrong..O.O

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: I'm very bad at probabilities, so I really don't know how I can solve this problem in a correct way. I thought maybe this question will be modeled in a Markov Chain, but not sure though.